# Convert GMT Diff to .Net timezone?

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

My database has GMT Diff for every country like **GMT+02:00** and **GMT-04:00**
Using C# .net is there a simple way to convert that to an actual an .Net timezone?

*e.g. "Eastern Standard Time" or "E. Australia Standard Time"*

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find *a* timezone, just not that likely the one you want.  The UTC offset is ambiguous.  GMT+02:00 is the offset for

- Jordan Standard Time
- GTB Standard Time
- Middle East Standard Time
- Egypt Standard Time
- Syria Standard Time
- South Africa Standard Time
- FLE Standard Time
- Israel Standard Time
- E. Europe Standard Time

Any you like in particular?  You'd get them with an expression like this:

```
    public static TimeZoneInfo[] GetTimeZones(TimeSpan offset) {
        return TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Where(z => z.BaseUtcOffset == offset).ToArray();
    }
```

I had to look some of these up.  FLE = Finland, Lithuania, Estonia.  GTB is tougher, I'm guessing at Greece, Turkey, Bulgaria.

Comment: I wonder what is the maximum number of different named timezones for a single offset.....

Comment: Don't forget about timezones that are GMT+2 when they're in Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: @David, it is UTC+02:00 with 9.  Notable odd-balls are Nepal, UTC+05:45, UTC+11:00 where nobody lives and Tonga, UTC+13:00 ignoring the date line.

Comment: I was referring to timezones like Central European Time, which is UTC+1 in the winter, but become Central European Summer Time, UTC+2, in the summer. So the total list of timezones that UTC+2 can refer to is more than just the 9.

Comment: @David, the other, daylight saving time is a political decision, not covered by timezones.  Traditionally in the USA states like Indiana and Arizona because they are on the fringe, and American Indian tribes that make there own rules.    Powerful idea, people do get to call their own rule.  And never a problem when the train doesn't stop in your town.

Comment: @Hans Sometimes I think you really do know everything!!

Comment: Meh, hardly.  Used to collect stamps as a kid.

Comment: @Hans I don't understand what you're saying. All timezones are political decisions, that's why they don't carve out precise 15 degree sections of the globe. What I'm saying is, if he's got a UTC offset, to get the full list of timezones that have that offset, he would need to include the timezones that have that offset during summer time. You don't have Central European Summer Time in your list, but it is UTC+02:00.

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to be possible because different time zones can share the same offset from GMT (or UTC to be more correct).

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting "Eastern Standard Time" out of it, you need more information than just the offset from GMT. For example, GMT-5 is Eastern Standard Time, Central Daylight Time, Eastern Standard Time (Indiana), and various South American time zones, both with and without Daylight Saving, and on a different DST schedule than the US.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with just the first available TimeZone which matches that GMT offset, that should be easy.

This is off my head but...

```
TimeZoneInfo getTimeZone(string gmtstring)
{
  foreach(TimeZoneInfo ti in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
  {
    TimeSpan tsp = ti.BaseUtcOffset;
    if(tsp.ToString((tsp.TotalMinutes < 0 ? "-" : "+")+"hh:mm") == gmtstring.Substring(3))
      return ti;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Otherwise there's no direct relation between timezones and GMT offsets (there are many timezones on the same GMT offset, as the others said)

PS: gmtstring should be in the "GMT(+|-)HH:SS" format