# Get Standard Time Zone Name using C#

Tags: c#, timezone

i need to get std time zone name by time zone using c#..

for ex if i give +05.30.0 means it will show std indian time zone...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert GMT Diff to .Net timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927170/convert-gmt-diff-to-net-timezone)

Comment: @Yogee The simple solution is convert everything to UTC time.  You need to explain what you mean exactly by +5.30.0 I have NEVER in all my years seen a timezone describe like that.  If you go the UTC time you can simply add the offset to the value or figure out what timezone the user is in and go from that value.  If you do everything based on UTC it makes everything easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TimeZone has a StandardName property.
Please refer to the examples at the [|MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.standardname%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Edit: if all you want are the timezone *names*, then you can use the workaround underlined [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/247880-c-time-zone). Also, check [this class](http://www.michaelbrumm.com/simpletimezone.html) for easy manipulation of timezones.